Accesing express server for auth2 return cors error
Im on production trying to use google auth 2.0 with passport on my express js backend.
origin: function(origin, callback) {
 if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
   callback(null, origin); // Return the specific origin, not a wildcard
 } else {
   callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS policy'));
 }
},
credentials: true,
methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],
allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Accept'],
exposedHeaders: ['Set-Cookie']
}));

on my protected route (frontend) I fetch check-auth
          credentials: 'include', 
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });   ````

and I get a cors error ```Access to fetch at 'https://api.remarc.me/api/v1/auth/check-auth' from origin 'https://www.remarc.me' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.```

pulled my hair for 12 hours now ! nothing worked 

login logic: I git api/v1/auth - > backend redirects to google -> callback url is dashboard that is a protected route and on protected route we check-auth 

Thank you for your help :) 



What do you mean here, "backend redirects to google"? Are you saying that you are trying to send the user to the Google authorization dialog URL? You can't request that URL in the background, you need to redirect the frontend there directly.

I mean form the frontend I hit backend/api/v1/auth/google and the backend does this router.get('/google',
passport.authenticate('google', {
scope: ['profile', 'email'],
prompt: 'select_account'
})
);

You can not fetch the Google auth dialog URL in the background. Which also means, if you have an endpoint that redirects there, you must also not fetch that endpoint in the background in the first place. You need to send the user there directly.
